# Display only full screen YouTube video with WebView (not show comment etc...)

Tags: webview, youtube, fullscreen

I want to display YouTube videos with fullscreen. So I tried the codes below, but all of them show show white screen (not work). Both of these two buttons don't work (I tried embedded one and URL without embedded). How could I set my codes:

```
floatingActionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            wv.loadUrl("<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNhTOm1DNFE\"\n" + "                allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"\n" + "                mozallowfullscreen=\"mozallowfullscreen\"\n" + "                msallowfullscreen=\"msallowfullscreen\"\n" + "                oallowfullscreen=\"oallowfullscreen\"\n" + "                webkitallowfullscreen=\"webkitallowfullscreen\"> </iframe>");
        }
    });
    floatingActionButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wv.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/p2KnvF0hkLI?autoplay=1");
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you're using a WebView and you have a webpage as middleman, I guess it'd be easier because many WordPress themes are able to do so. I can say I'm able to do a similar thing regarding [Vimeo](https://quaestio.org/portfolio/vertentes/) with the help from the [theme](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/salient-responsive-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/4363266?_ga=2.161353663.340824023.1521272705-1402465435.1473954114) I use and it'd be simple to load the premade WebView instead. I suggest you to check how themes like this work to have a better understanding of the case. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but I dont know your methods. I could use android studio webview. I thought everything is correct but it didnt work.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's done (actually I never checked it closely). I just thought you could use a webpage to land the clean video and then load it by the means of Android since you'll be using a WebView anyway, but maybe it's not the case (I'm not sure if you're using a web domain). I just say so because I think it'd be really easier. For instance, I'd be able to simply load the webpage with clean Vimeo videos using a basic WebView model this way. Even though it'd be hard to get the play button out of the view I guess.